# Width 100 % gets outside the parent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a `div#firstdiv`. Inside that div I have other `div#otherdiv` and the width of them is a % of `#firstdiv`. Also, this others div have a specific margin left who should not be influenced by the other `#otherdiv` but my problem is when I do `position :absolute; widht:100%` the #otherdiv goes outside #firstdiv. Let see an example. I have :

```
<div style=" width: 500px; border: 2px solid red; height: 150px; >
     <div style="width: 100%; position: absolute; border: 1px solid blue; >here<div>
</div>
```

And I have the following result :

[image]

And I want the blue div being inside the red one. It works if I do `position absolute` If I had another `#otherdiv`
 the margin-left depend on what's already there and I dont want that.

I that change anything : I'm working with bootstrap and my these two dive are inside

`<div class="container-fluid container-first"><div class="container">`

Comment: This is due to `position: absolute`. It's `absolute` related to to the `document`.

Comment: I know but if i don't my margin-left don't work the way I want

Comment: Try `position: relative` and if it doesn't work please provide some minimal example of your code not working (with this margin-left issue you mention).

Comment: currently the inner div is relative to the view port because it has no other ancestor with position relative or absolute, therefore it takes the viewport's width add `position: relative; `to the parent div as the others have mentioned

Comment: Don't give it any position unless you actually want to position it, like `left:0;`, ` right:0 ;` or whatever. In this current code, you just need to remove the `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Position: absolute` removes an element from the normal flow of the content. Its parent behaves as if the `absolute` element is not there at all. Therefore, you need to relatively position its parent. Add `position:relative` for its parent to do so. For more info, visit [`css-tricks`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/#article-header-id-1)

```html
<div style=" width: 500px; border: 2px solid red; height: 150px; position: relative" >
     <div style="width: 100%; position: absolute; border: 1px solid blue;" >here<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `position relative` to the parent  like so

```
<div style=" width: 500px; border: 2px solid red; height: 150px; position: relative" >
             <div style="width: 100%; position: absolute; border: 1px solid blue;">here</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need the position: absolute for what you're trying to accomplish.

The inner `<div>` element with the blue borders should automatically become a block type element and fill the width of its parent element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>        
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width: 500px; border: 2px solid red; height: 150px;">
        <div style="border: 1px solid blue;">
            here
        </div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid blue;">
            otherDiv
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -4):

Put a `float:left;` to the inner div and remove your `position:absolute;` this should work.